# How to detect the closing of the NofiticationCenter in Swift / Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, viewdidload, viewdidappear

I have a UITableView and I want to to reload, when the NotificationCenter has been dismissed over the running app.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"dismissedNC", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

}

func dismissedNC() {

    println("NC has been dismissed") // doesn't get printed
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the notification center was present, the app was never in the background, so it does not come to the foreground when the notification center is dismissed - and so there is no `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`. The app is *activated*, not *foregrounded*. Watch for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` instead.

Comment: Of course, that's going to raise further issues, but I guess you'll cross that bridge when you come it. The real problem is that you have no way of knowing exactly why and when the app is activated. Maybe the notification center was present, maybe not. You cannot find out.

Comment: Great, works like a charme! `    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"dismissedNC", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)`